# How to move a local volume onto a remote docker machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, docker-volume

I have my local docker machine and a remote docker machine, on the cloud. My docker-compose app has a `web`container with this config:

```
web:
  container_name: web
  restart: always
  build: ./web
  expose:
    - "8000"
  links:
    - postgres:postgres
  volumes:
    - /usr/src/app/static
    - ./data:/usr/src/app/data
  env_file: .env
  command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn --workers 4 --timeout 120 --bind :8000 app:app
```

The important part is that second volume. I have this local folder called data with some 10GB of data in it. I made it a volume in the first place because otherwise building the container takes forever. Now that the app is production-ready, I'd like to deploy it. One problem: now my remote `web` container has an empty data folder mounted in it. So how do I move data from my local machine into a container on a remote docker machine? Where do I even move it *to*?

It seems like there are two tools for this:

- `docker cp` which doesn't seem like it will work for remote docker machines
- `docker-machine scp` which seems made for this, right?

I'm almost positive I need to use the second of these, but since I don't quite understand how docker machine works or where it keeps its data, I'm not sure what destination path to use:

```
  $  dm scp -r /Users/alex/Documents/Project/data remote-machine:/usr/src/app/data
```

fails with error message:

`scp: /usr/src/app/data: No such file or directory`

Where should I be scp'ing this data in order to have it mount properly on my remote `web` container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Local path vs. in-container path

Assuming you will use the same model remotely that you used locally, keep in mind that the path `/usr/src/app/data` is the path *inside* the container. When you are copying the files from one system to another, you just need to copy them from the current system to the remote system, then put them in a path where docker-compose knows how to find them, to mount into a new container.

So all you have to do is copy them from here to there, and use the same path *relative to* `docker-compose.yml`. It only knows your external volume as `./data`, so if you put the directory in the same place (from docker-compose's perspective), everything should work the same.

### How to copy the files

As for how to do the copy, these are just files, so it doesn't matter. `scp -r` should work, or make a zipfile, copy that, unzip into the correct place, etc. There are a ton of ways to copy files, so pick whatever is simplest for your case.

### What exactly needs to be copied?

In the comments you expressed confusion about local vs. remote operations in docker-machine, and what else you needed to copy. Here's a bit more full of an explanation:

On your local system (which I'm assuming is your own PC or laptop), you have docker-machine installed, and you've been using that for all of this development. Completely separate from that is your new cloud instance where you would like to deploy.

To run what you have locally already, up on your cloud instance, the cloud instance will need to have the following.

1. The `docker-compose.yml` file.

   As long as you plan to use docker-compose to run this, that must be available.
2. Your `.env` file.

   Since you are using an environment file in this setup, it must be available or docker-compose can't make use of it.
3. Your `web` image.

   You have a `build` parameter for this container, but not an `image` parameter. So currently the only thing you can do is `docker-compose build web` which will locally generate an image, which docker-compose then knows how to run.

   Another option is to add an `image` parameter, with a `repository:tag`, such as `myuser/myapp_web:1.0`, and push that up to Docker Hub. Then, on your cloud instance, the image can be retrieved from Docker Hub instead of building it locally.

   In that case, you can add an `image` parameter to the `web` container in docker-compose.yml, then build it and push it up.

   ```
   docker-compose build web
   docker-compose push web
   ```

   Then on the cloud instance, you can fetch it:

   ```
   docker-compose pull web
   ```

   docker-compose will know to use that image because of the `image` parameter in docker-compose.yml (which is also present on the cloud server).

   Ref: [Creating a new repository on Docker Hub](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/repos/#/creating-a-new-repository-on-docker-hub)

   Which of these options is preferable depends on how you want to manage things. Either one would work, but the "local build" option would require you copy any required source files to your cloud instance too (anything that is used during the build process).
4. I don't see in your question where the `postgres` container comes from. If you are also custom-building this one, then the same goes as for `web`. If you are using a public image for this, then you shouldn't need to copy anything; docker-compose will know how to fetch it, i.e. you can do this:

   ```
   docker-compose pull postgres
   ```

### What about docker cp and docker-machine scp?

You mentioned `docker cp` and `docker-machine scp` in your question.

As you already determined, `docker cp` is not a solution here. That command is for copying files between a container and the host filesystem. It has nothing to do with copying over a network.

As far as I know, `docker-machine scp` is to copy files between your local host and a `docker-machine`-managed VM. To copy files to your cloud instance you can likely use a more generic tool like scp or sftp more easily.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I'm still just a little confused, largely by how docker-machine kind of makes opaque to execute instructions on the remote docker machine as if it were my local machine. On the remote docker machine, I can't find a docker-compose file for example, nor any other file from my project that is meant to live outside of the containers themselves. So I don't really know where to put the `data` when I upload it, or how to edit the docker-compose file to edit to set the path for my remote volume. Does that make sense?

Comment: Strangely, I just realized that there is a `/Users/alex/Documents/Project/data` on the remote machine that seems to have been created but is empty. I'd docker-machine scp the data into that folder and see what happens, but now I'm getting a permission denied error!

Comment: @AlexLenail If the mount directory doesn't exist, docker-machine will create an empty one. Most likely owned by the running uid of whatever is running inside the container. (The user defined in a `USER` statement in Dockerfile, or if there isn't one, the default is root.) If you create the directory yourself instead of letting docker-compose do it, then you should be the owner.

Comment: @AlexLenail Oh also I updated my answer a couple of minutes ago, if you haven't read the updated version. I added some more info about what needs to be copied and why.

Comment: @AlexLenail Updated my answer again with some mention of docker hub push/pull for images.

Comment: thanks so much for your thorough answer. I just have one last question about docker before I finish this project. If you would be willing, I'd much appreciate if you took a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41656981/how-to-exit-docker-run-containers-once-the-script-those-containers-execute-cal

Answer (score 0):

Not sure as of which docker version, but contrary to the statements in the question and the @Dan_Lowe answer this works fine:

```
docker cp ./data container:/usr/src/app/
```

`docker cp` is a normal part of the API, so it works like any other command, even remotely.