# How to exit "docker run" containers once the script those containers execute calls exit()

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose setup, which is deployed in three steps:

1. Build all the containers and `dc up -d` (`dc` is an alias for `docker-compose`)
2. Create database with: `dc run web /usr/local/bin/python create_db.py`
3. Populate database with: `dc run -d web /usr/local/bin/python -u manage.py populateDB`

Steps 2 and 3 create new containers (see the first two):

```
~/Documents/Project » docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                              PORTS                    NAMES
2ead532ea58b        myproject_web       "/usr/local/bin/pytho"   8 minutes ago       Up 8 minutes                        8000/tcp                 myproject_web_run_2
64e1f81ecd1a        myproject_web       "/usr/local/bin/pytho"   9 minutes ago       Restarting (0) About a minute ago   8000/tcp                 myproject_web_run_1
9f5c670d4d7f        myproject_nginx     "/usr/sbin/nginx"        40 minutes ago      Up 40 minutes                       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp       myproject_nginx_1
46d3e8c09c03        myproject_web       "/usr/local/bin/gunic"   40 minutes ago      Up 40 minutes                       8000/tcp                 myproject_web_1
ea876e68c8c6        postgres:latest     "/docker-entrypoint.s"   40 minutes ago      Up 40 minutes                       0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   myproject_postgres_1
```

Which is all well and good, except they ***don't exit when their job is finished***.

For example, the create db script, as you can see, is always restarting after it has created the database. Once `achromap_web_run_2` has finished populating the database, it will add a second copy of each record, then a third, etc.. forever.

On github, it seems like this was asked for from docker, and the `docker run --rm` flag handles it. But `--rm` and `-d` are incompatible, which I don't understand.

Do you know how to kill containers which have finished executing their functions? Specifically, how to get `dc run web /usr/local/bin/python create_db.py` to exit once create_db.py calls `exit()`? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be conflating two things here.

### The --rm flag

This exists to clean up after a container is finished, so it doesn't hang around in the dead containers pool. As you already found, it is not compatible with `-d`. But in this case, you don't need it anyway.

### The --restart flag

(Also available in docker-compose as the `restart` property.)

This flag sets the restart policy. By default it is set to `no`, but you can set it to a few other values, including `always`. I would suspect you have it set to `always` currently, which would force the container to restart every time it stops on its own.

If you manually stop the container (`docker stop ...`) then the auto-restart would not engage. But if the process exits on its own, or crashes, then the container will be restarted. This is available for the obvious reason, so your service will start up again if it crashes.

### How to proceed

I would say what you need is to use `exec` instead of `run` for these tasks.

First, run your container normally (i.e. `docker-compose up -d`).

Instead of using `run` to execute `create_db.py`, use `exec`.

```
docker-compose exec web /usr/local/bin/python create_db.py
```

This will use your already-running container, execute the script one time, and when the script exits, you're done. Since you did not create a new container (like `run` was doing), there is no cleanup to do afterward.

Note that you do not need the `-it` flag that is often used with `docker exec`. docker-compose emulates a tty on `exec` by default.

Comment: Is there a way to monitor progress of a docker exec task? I'm now doing `docker exec web -d web /usr/local/bin/python -u manage.py populateDB` but I can't monitor the progress of my DB populating because I can't find the log statements I had put in the populateDB function.

Comment: @AlexLenail If you drop the `-d` you can just watch stdout... Do you need it to be detached for a specific reason?

Comment: `populateDB` takes about a day, and I'd rather not keep my machine open and running throughout that. I can alternatively `dm ssh` and then `nohup docker exec` which might have the same outcome.

Comment: My `web` container has `restart: always` which makes sense for the web container, but not for the containers which run tasks for web. I need to think this through a little more, specifically about the differences between `docker-compose run` and `docker run`.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a Python script to stop all the docker containers and remove them when one of the containers exits. As for docker compose files there is no flag to stop the containers once one them exits. You can modify it the way you like, for example instead of docker-compose you can use docker run commands as well in the functions "start_docker_services" and "docker_services_watcher".

```
import os, time, multiprocessing


# Process class
class Process(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, id):
        super(Process, self).__init__()
        self.id = id
  
    def run(self):

        if self.id == 0:
            start_docker_services()
        
        if self.id == 1:
            docker_services_watcher()


def start_docker_services():
    os.system("docker compose up --build")


def docker_services_watcher():

    print("\ndocker services watcher will start in 10 seonds.")
    time.sleep(10)

    # all containers (reading how many containers are running)
    mydata = os.popen("docker compose ps").read()
    # print("\n", mydata)

    keep_running = True
    
    # as every service run on a port so we are counting the string tcp 
    total_services_in_start = mydata.count("/tcp")

    while keep_running:

        current_total_services = os.popen("docker compose ps").read().count("/tcp")

        if current_total_services == total_services_in_start:
            print(
                f"all services are running, total services: \
                {current_total_services} / {total_services_in_start}"
            )
            time.sleep(5) # after every 5 seconds will check again
        else:
            print("one of the service stopped, closing docker containers...")
            keep_running = False

    os.system("docker compose down")


if __name__ == '__main__':


    p = Process(0)
    p.start()

    p = Process(1)
    p.start()
    p.join()
```